# How can I print a hash of hashes of hashes in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a `$map{k1}{k2}{k3}{k4}`.

How can I write the loop correctly to print all values? The following does not work.

```
for my $k1 (sort keys %tripletsCountMap) {
    for my $k2 (sort keys %$tripletsCountMap{k1}){
        for my $k3 (sort keys %$tripletsCountMap{k1}{k2}) {
            for my $k4 (sort keys %$tripletsCountMap{k1}{k3}{k3}){
                print "$k1 $k2 $k3 $k4\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would never do this. IRL you would use `Data::Dumper` (displays native perl structure that will work in an eval), or `XXX.pm` (uses YAML for output). This is what we call a recursive data structure.. Keep in mind your code only supports 4-depth, rather than n-depth an arbitrary limit on depth is uncommon in a recursive structure. You might want to look up tree-recursion for how this should be done.

Comment: You have a typo. You use `{k1}{k3}{k3}` -- did you mean `{k1}{k` **`2`** `}{k3}`? (Additionally, as others have pointed out, you actually want `$k1` not `k1` etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Note that there is a difference between [**`k1`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Barewords) and **`$k1`**.

```
for my $k1 (sort keys %tripletsCountMap) {
    for my $k2 (sort keys %{ $tripletsCountMap{$k1} }){
        for my $k3 (sort keys %{ $tripletsCountMap{$k1}{$k2} }) {
            for my $k4 (sort keys %{ $tripletsCountMap{$k1}{$k2}{$k3} }){
                printf "$k1 $k2 $k3 $k4: $tripletsCountMap{$k1}{$k2}{$k3}{$k4}\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Better yet:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%tripletsCountMap;
```

<s>And, why are you sorting the keys?</s> I understand the point @ysth in the comments below. I am just not in the habit of sorting the keys of a hash when I iterate over them unless there is some explicit output related requirement.

Comment: unless there are huge performance implications (usually not the case), looping over sorted keys is a very good idea.  it frees you from a whole class of perl version/platform/data dependent bugs where the loop body somehow depends on one key being processed before another.

Comment: Sorting (extra-work) to remove a possible user-dependency that was /never/ supported sounds silly. I would suggest removing the sort if this was your logic.

Answer (score 4):

If this is for debugging or similar purposes, it's probably better to use `Data::Dumper` to do this sort of thing. It's intelligent enough to follow through the data structure and get it right.

Answer (score 4):

When using % to dereference an expression, the expression must be enclosed in {} unless it's a simple scalar (e.g. `%$href`).

I recommend you read http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.

Answer (score 2):

Poor man's Dumper:

```
sub trace {
    my ( $val, $path ) = @_;
    my $ref = ref $val;
    if ( $ref eq '' ) {
        print "$path = $val\n";
    }
    elsif ( $ref eq 'HASH' ) {
        trace( $val->{$_}, $path . "{$_}" ) for keys %$val;
    }
    elsif ( $ref eq 'ARRAY' ) {
        trace( $val->[$_], $path . "[$_]" ) for 0 .. $#$val;
    }
    else {
        warn "I don't know what to do with $ref at $path\n";
    }
}

trace($map, '$map->');
```

Answer (score 1):

$k1 is the variable, k1 is a [bareword](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Barewords).

```
perl -e '%h = (1 => 2, "k1" => 3); $k1 = 1; printf "%d %d\n", $h{$k1}, $h{k1}'
```

2 3

Then if you use hash reference be cautious to use scalar variables to store them.

```
perl -e '$h = {1 => 2, "k1" => 3}; $k1 = 1; printf "%d %d\n", $h->{$k1}, $h->{k1}'
```

2 3

If you happened to write something like nothing will work as expected:

```
perl -e '%h = {1 => 2, "k1" => 3}; $k1 = 1; printf "%d %d\n", $h->{$k1}, $h->{k1}'
```

0 0

If the bareword is not the problem (it probably is), then you should carefully check how you built your map.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing all the keys but not the final value.

In the most inner loop add:

```
my $val = $map{$k1}{$k2}{$k3}{$k4};
print "$val\n";
```

Comment: Actually nothing is printed. In my code at least $1 ... $4 must be printed right, even though the value is not printed.

Comment: Have you added `use strict;` to the top of your program?

Comment: @ajay: There is a difference between **`$1`** and **`$k1`** and **`k1`**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code:
this will work

```
while(my($key1,$value1)=each(%hash_hash)){
  while(my($key2,$value2)=each(%$value1)){
       print $key1."=".$key2."=".$value2."\n";
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

yet another way:

```
 while (my ($first,$second) = each (%hash_hash_hash_hash)) {
    while (my ($second, $third) = each (%$second)) {
        while (my ($third, $fourth) = each (%$third)) {
            while (my ($fourth, $value) = each (%$fourth)) {
                print "$first\t$second\t$third\t$fourth\t$value\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```